# Finding the highest sum of each list in a nested list and then printing the highest list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, max

So I have this task to find the list with highest sum in a nested list and I'm stuck.So far I have tried :

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
total = 0
limit = int(input('Number of Lists: '))

for i in range(0,limit):
    numbs = [int(x) for x in input('Enter List: ').split()]
    list_1.append(numbs)
for y in range(0, len(list_1[0])):
    for z in range(0, len(list_1)):
        total = total + list_1[z][y]
        list_2.append(total)
print(list_1)
print(list_2)
```

The output I get:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
[22, 48, 78]
Why is there even three values? I have four sublists
```

The Output I need:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
[6, 15, 24, 33]
```

Comment: Walk through your `for y` and `for z` loops, and really think about what they're doing.

Comment: ... and then conclude that the only code you need is `max(list_1, key=sum)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do this with `for-loop` like below:

```
>>> list_1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
>>> list_2 = [sum(l) for l in list_1]
>>> list_2
[6, 15, 24, 33]

# finding max in each list
>>> lst_mx = [max(l) for l in list_1]
>>> lst_mx
[3, 6, 9, 12]

# list have maximun sum
>>> max(list_1, key=sum)
[10, 11, 12]
```

You can do this with `dictionary` like below:

```
>>> dct = {sum(l) : l for l in list_1}
>>> dct
{6: [1, 2, 3], 15: [4, 5, 6], 24: [7, 8, 9], 33: [10, 11, 12]}

>>> dct[max(dct)]
[10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: But then how will I print the maximum values list?

Comment: No I mean print the sublist the max value comes from like: 33 , [10,11,12]

Comment: @Irrelevant I misunderstand, edited answer

Comment: @user1740577 thanks now I understand. this is out of topic. but let me ask you something. I'm at first semester of university and the faculty says not to use built in functions as much as possible. Is that gonna be a problem in terms of getting a job or real world applications?

Comment: Yes, don't use [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as variable, because you got error, run this code: `lst=[1,2,3]; len = 3; len_lst=len(lst);` you got error : `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` because here, I use built-in function `len` as variable.

Comment: @Irrelevant you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks way to complicated.

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
O = []
for i in L:
    O.append(sum(i))
print(O)
```

The for loop iterates over your input list `L`. Then the `sum` functions calculates the sum of the 4 sub lists and appends it to the output array.

If you then need the list with the highest sum, you can print the sub list at the index of the highest number in `O`.

```
maxIndex = O.index(max(O))
print(L[maxIndex])
```

Comment: Ok, but it can simply be achieved by `max(list_1, key=sum)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```py
for y in range(0, len(list_1[0])):
    for z in range(0, len(list_1)):
        total = total + list_1[z][y]
        list_2.append(total)
```

use this `list_2 = [sum(i) for i in list_1]`

Comment: This is not what OP asks

Comment: @DeepSpace what is OP?